# Auto save data without even opening google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this but I just want to know if this is even possible. In google sheets, I am trying to build a 1 day stock chart. I know I can get the current price, but not hourly prices back. Can I Set up a script that will run at a certain time every day to record the price at that moment. Even without having the spreadsheet open?

Not looking for a code unless its something easy someone can throw out there, just want to know if it is possible to have it auto run or what function or what technique would work.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: It's possible to write a script that will read and save cell values with Google Finance formulas and be triggered from a time based trigger.

Comment: You can try `.copyTo()` with a time trigger,

Comment: Is the price data you want to get hourly located in a spreadsheet or do you catch it from somewhere else?